# Finding transformation from $T : \Bbb R^5 \rightarrow \Bbb R^4 $ ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Is there a Linear Transformation from $T : \Bbb R^5 \rightarrow \Bbb R^4 $ so $$\operatorname{Ker}T = \{(
x,y,z,t,w) \in \Bbb R^5 \; | \; x = 2y, \text{ and, } z = 2t = 3w\}$$
if so find an example of this transformation. It's enough to define it on base $\Bbb R^5 $. If not, explain why.

Well I tried to solve it and I'm not sure that what I've done was correct...
I said that $x=2y$ , $z=3w$ and $t=\frac{3w}{2}$  so it should look like this

$$\operatorname{Ker}T = \left\{\left(
2y,y,3w,\frac{3w}{2},w \right) \right\}$$ so I got $x$ and $w$ out in order to get 2 vectors...
$$\operatorname{Ker}T = \left\{y(
2,1,0,0,0)+w \left( 0,0,3,\frac{3}{2},1 \right) \right\}$$ I changed the second vector so it will be nicer and get $y$ and $w$ out so..

$$\operatorname{Ker}T = \operatorname{Sp}\{(
2,1,0,0,0),(0,0,6,3,2)\}$$

Hopefully so far I'm correct?
since they are kernal i can say that:

$T(2,1,0,0,0)=(0,0,0,0)$ and $T(0,0,6,3,2)=(0,0,0,0)$

from here I defined 3 more vectors from (which I made)

$$T(0,1,0,0,0)=(0,1,0,0), T(0,0,0,1,0)=(0,0,1,0) \text{ and } T(0,0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0,1)$$

I wrote those matrix and used row reduction in order to see that it's not linearly dependent and because of that it is a base (english is not my main language so sorry if I didn't write it correctly)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 2 \\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1\end{bmatrix};$$

and we get

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1\end{bmatrix};$$

so it must be a base therefore since $T(v_i)  =w_i$ 
for each $i=1,2...n$.
and it is linear transformation...
Is it correct or am I wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: You've written a $5\times5$ matrix, which corresponds to a transformation from ${\bf R}^5$ to ${\bf R}^5$, not to ${\bf R}^4$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well then how can i fix that?
i thought that if i proove that B(which contain those vectors) is a base for $R^5$ then each of his vectors has atleast of tranformation to $R^4$

Comment: You mean I need to substract one of the KerT's vector and make it 4x5 matrix? And thus, it will be from $R^5$ to $R^4$?

Comment: Never mind. I thought you intended your matrix to be the matrix representing the transformation, but now I see you were using the matrix to prove you have a basis for ${\bf R}^5$. Since you have a basis, and since the range of the transformation clearly has dimension 3, you're done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson then im correct and have no mistake?
I were unsure at this thank you very much :)
if you find anything please write me in need to send this work until next week and this is the only question i think i might have an error at

Comment: @GerryMyerson Since I proved I've a basis for $R^5$, if I want to give an example of a transformation by using $T_A = A(x)$ whereas the A represents a matrix from $R^4 to R^5$ can I take the two span vectors in Span KerT and add them to a third vector and substract them to a fourth vector and then I'll have a 4x5 matrix which is a linear transformation from R4 to R5 or there's another way to find that matrix? You don't have to answer it's just for my knowledge, thanks.

Comment: The question asks for a map from ${\bf R}^5$ to ${\bf R}^4$, but now you want one from ${\bf R}^4$ to ${\bf R}^5$? From ${\bf R}^5$ to ${\bf R}^4$, you need a matrix with 4 rows and 5 columns. You don't want the kernel vectors to be the rows of this matrix, you want them to be orthogonal to the rows of the matrix.